# Best way to connect HBASE with SPARK in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, bigdata

Which is the best way to access all the rows of HBASE into SPARK for Data Analysis? Tried `StarBase` to pickup data but it loads data into memory! whats the best alternative for the whole process?

Comment: Which distribution do you have ? Horton ? Cloudera ?

Comment: Raw distribution.. directly from apache

Comment: Arf... Can you try something like that : http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Include-latest-hbase-spark-in-CDH/m-p/43236/highlight/true#M2280? I'm not sure it's going to work but... :)

Comment: hehe.. Sorry, But its a better way to find a solution to handle it in code rather than reconfiguring everywhere :P @Xire

Comment: The exemple show how manipulate HBase in Spark with python...

Comment: Am searching  for examples for past few days.. But cant find a good one !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153349/discussion-between-jerin-k-john-and-xire).

Comment: has there been any progress on this? There is no good example anywhere, especially when working with raw distribution from apache.